# Input stays extend after focus

Tags: css, input

I want to have a textarea input which extends when it's focus **AND** stays extended when looses focus. Is it possible to do so **only with css**?

I currently have:

```
.expend-input:focus {
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superalligator/ep4dzv1x/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible because you are changing state. That is something that has to do with functionality.

CSS is only there to describe your HTML document.

You would have to use a little bit of JS in here to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

no, you can't do it only with css, because there is no way in css to differentiate between the state before the focus and after. (the focus is a css pseudo class and it's temporary)